# JFace Databinding Does Not Support Default Methods

Tags: java, eclipse-plugin, jface

There was a surprising new feature in Java 8: default methods on interfaces. So surprising in fact that even the JDK's very own bean [Introspector does not support](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8071693?page=com.atlassian.streams.streams-jira-plugin:activity-stream-issue-tab) it. And since Java 8 is brand new, having only been released for a year or so, it's probably safe to assume it will not get fixed that soon.

All of that means that the JFace Databinding can not possible support default methods either, which is a problem, as you can imagine. We already have a own Instrospector, but has anybody any idea how we could extend / fix / patch the databinding to use that instead of the nonworking default one?

Some details: for the interface of the bug report:

```
public static interface Named {

    public default String getName() {
        return "always the same";
    }
}
```

The exception would look like that:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: name property does not have a read method.
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.databinding.beans.BeanPropertyHelper.readProperty(BeanPropertyHelper.java:94)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.databinding.beans.PojoValueProperty.doGetValue(PojoValueProperty.java:47)
    at org.eclipse.core.databinding.property.value.ValueProperty.getValue(ValueProperty.java:57)
```

We do use databinding 1.4.0, which is the version the download site provides even for Eclipse 4.4.2, I saw a version 1.4.2 somewhere, but after some fruitless tries I'm starting to believe it's beyond my capabilities to swap the plug-in.

Comment: Could you clarify if you actually tried to bind a default method or if you assume that it does not work?

Comment: @RüdigerHerrmann If you bind with `PojoObservables.observeValue(object, "name")` it uses the default Java Introspector, even in newest JFace versions. So there's no possible way for it to work.

Comment: I can succeefully bind with `PojoProperties.value( Pojo.class, "defaultMethod" ).observe( dataBindingContext.getValidationRealm(), pojo )` where Pojo.class is an interface with `set/getDefaultMethod()` - not entirely sure where the difference to `PojoObservables.observeValue()` lies. If that's not a viable woraround for you - have you looked into replacing `PojoProperties.value`?  This is where the call of observeValue ends and the `PropertyDescriptor` is obtained. With some luck you'd be able to use your own `PropertyDescriptor`-derived implementation.

Comment: @RüdigerHerrmann It does not work with `PojoProperties.value(...).observe(...)` either with `org.eclipse.core.databinding` 1.4.0, which is the version the download site provides even for Eclipse 4.4.2 (which of course we're not using).

Answer (score 0):

I was able to bind to a property backed by default methods when specifying the interface type like this:

```
IObservableValue observableValue = PojoProperties.value( Named.class, "name" ).observe( realm, named );
observableValue.setValue( "name" );
```

If this approach doesn'twork for you, you could create a `PojoValueProperty` yourself and pass in the custom-created `PropertyDescriptor`.

```
PropertyDescriptor propertyDescriptor = ...
IObservableValue observableValue = new PojoValueProperty( propertyDescriptor, null ).observe( realm, named );
```

But you'll see that the above code accesses internal classes and you likely want to copy the property-name-split-code of `PojoObservables.value()`

Comment: Maybe that's the reason why this wouldn't work for me: we have beans, that might or might not inherit methods from an interface, so we can only bind against the bean class. But there are a lot of other frameworks that don't support this, either, so we figured we had to go the painful way of changing the beans to override the interface method (calling super) until everybody does.